# How to create chart analogue to Custom Tables with two nominal variables on X-axis?

Tags: data-visualization, spss, categorical-data

The variables are

- A with values A1 to A4
- B with values B1 to B3
- C with values C1 and C2

I managed to create a custom table with three nominal variables using the Analyze > Tables > Custom Tables function like this:

```
                        C
                    C1      C2

A   A1      B   B1  nnn     nnn
                B2  nnn     nnn
                B3  nnn     nnn
    A2      B   B1  nnn     nnn
                B2  nnn     nnn
                B3  nnn     nnn
    A3      B   B1  nnn     nnn
                B2  nnn     nnn
                B3  nnn     nnn
    A4      B   B1  nnn     nnn
                B2  nnn     nnn
                B3  nnn     nnn
```

Is it possible to create the corresponding clustered bar chart with A and B on the X-axis and C as the color variable?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is use panels.

For example, via Graphs > Legacy Dialogs > Bar

Then choose Clustered Bar, and set Category Axis to B, Define Clusters by A, and add C to the columns.